# How to resolve the issue of Jar file not being created

Tags: react-native, expo, dependencies, gradlew

This is the Exception I encountered:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Bonga Hobeni.gradle\caches\jars-9\196b729407d7fbb2907378f4b4c34b5a\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.10.jar.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 54s

I was trying to use the command *gradlew clean* (*./gradlew clean* not working) to sync the gradlew so I can create an apk for my react native app on VS code. But now I'm facing this exception trying to do that and there's always some packages in IDLE during the process before the build fails.